# how to invoke unix command in perl

Tags: perl, unix

i am trying to execute following unix command but its not getting executed

```
$array_of_tables= `dbsmp $srv_name`;
print "$array_of_tables\n";
```

please help me to find out list of tables in a data base through perl scripting.

Also i am trying to copy a file from a path to different path by using following command:-

```
copy(`cd /osp/slee/service/$srv_name/bin/exec/script.txt`,`cd /osp/local/home/linus/amit/scripts`);
```

but getting an error:-

```
Usage: copy(FROM, TO [, BUFFERSIZE])
```

please provide some solution
Thanks

Comment: Your second command should simply be `copy('/osp/.../script.txt', '/osp/.../scripts');` (note the apostrophes are not backticks)

Comment: Just don't invoke external commands and use robust and portable core modules, http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use doublequotes instead of back ticks.

```
copy("/osp/slee/service/$srv_name/bin/exec/script.txt","/osp/local/home/linus/amit/scripts");
```

and remove the `cd`

Comment: Now i am not getting that particular error but file is not getting copied at the given path. Is there any other method to copy a file at unix platform in perl scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, the preferable way to capture the output of a system (shell) command is the `qx()` operator. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators.

```
$array_of_tables = qx(dbsmp $srv_name);
print("$array_of_tables\n");
```

Actually, backticks should also work, so the problem must lie with your dbsmp command. I'm not sure what that command is; you'll have to provide more information about the utility and what error you're seeing.

For comparison, I can retrieve the list of tables in my local postgres database as a pipe-separated table using this shell command:

```
> psql -tAXq main postgres <<<\\d;
```

And this can be run from Perl as follows:

```
> perl -e 'print(qx(psql -tAXq main postgres <<<\\\\d;));'
```

Comment: backticks *are* the qx operator (just like double quotes are qq and single quotes are q)